# relay-starter-kit failed on windows

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, relayjs

I installed the replay starter kit on my windows 10 machine, but I get errors after "npm start." The key failure seems to be at 'babel-node ./server.js'.

Here's my npm debug log:

```js
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.11.2
3 info using node@v0.12.5
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart relay-starter-kit@0.1.0
6 info start relay-starter-kit@0.1.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info relay-starter-kit@0.1.0 Failed to exec start script
9 verbose stack Error: relay-starter-kit@0.1.0 start: `babel-node ./server.js`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:213:16)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
10 verbose pkgid relay-starter-kit@0.1.0
11 verbose cwd C:\Users\Polisander\Code\miles-relay
12 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
13 error argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error node v0.12.5
15 error npm  v2.11.2
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error relay-starter-kit@0.1.0 start: `babel-node ./server.js`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the relay-starter-kit@0.1.0 start script 'babel-node ./server.js'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the relay-starter-kit package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     babel-node ./server.js
18 error You can get their info via:
18 error     npm owner ls relay-starter-kit
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```